# Can I play Cyberpunk Steam Edition on two devices with the same savegame?

Tags: steam, cyberpunk-2077

I wonder if Cyberpunk (resp. Steam) automatically saves my savegame in the cloud and if that is the case I can continue the game on another computer with very different Hardware (AMD GPU vs. NVIDIA GPU e.g.).

Maybe this is not even a Cyberpunk specific question and this applies for any game, whose savegames are uploaded, but hitherto, I have never used two devices for a Single Player game.

Comment: Easy to test this if you want using a free GeForce Now account to stream the game.

Comment: I've never heard of a game where saves were dependent on specific hardware, so I don't see that being an issue. (Assuming of course we're talking about the same platform. But if both are PCs, this shouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: @MichaelMior Several people lost their Payday 2 progress, because it doesn't synchronise anything to Steam Cloud. Instead, everything is within your Windows profile "appdata". A very specific case, but a rather fatal one when you've spent thousands worth of gameplay.

Comment: @Clockwork Sure, but not syncing to the cloud is different from the save not working on different machines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is more a question about Steam than Cyberpunk 2077. Steam allows you to synchronize saves across multiple devices. The Steam product page indicates that Cyberpunk 2077 supports Steam Cloud, so yes - as long as you're logged in on the same account on both devices, it should synchronize your save and allow you to continue where you left off.

This is certainly the case with other games that support Steam Cloud and is certainly the case when installing Cyberpunk 2077 via GOG so I anticipate no issues with using your synchronized save across multiple devices.

Answer (score -1):

I play Cyberpunk 2077 on Steam using my desktop at home.
When first booting up Cyberpunk using the Geforce-Now app on a second computer, I was able to continue where I left off and played throughout the day. (Save files synced from Steam)
After getting home I was able to play where I left off from Geforce-Now. (Save files synced from Geforce-Now)
However, when using Geforce-Now again the following day I was only able to access the save files from my previous time spent on Geforce-Now. (Save files from desktop NOT synced)

I'm unsure why this happened, and I hope when I boot up cyberpunk 2077 again on my desktop at home that my save files will be there.